# Group by 2d Array in numpys pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Whats the best approach to group 2d Arrays by day using python pandas.
I want to get the daily sum grouped by the 2d array. The result should also be an 2d Array.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from datetime import datetime

# create 72 hours of pseudo-data with 3 vertical levels and a 4 by 4
# horizontal grid.
data = np.ones((72, 3, 4))
t = pd.date_range(datetime(2008,7,1), freq='1H', periods=72)


s = pd.Series([data[i] for i in range(data.shape[0])],index=t)


2008-07-01 14:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-01 15:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-01 16:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-01 17:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-01 18:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-01 19:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-01 20:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-01 21:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-01 22:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-01 23:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-02 00:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-02 01:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-02 02:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-02 03:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-02 04:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-02 05:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
                                             ...                        
2008-07-02 18:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-02 19:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-02 20:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-02 21:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-02 22:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
2008-07-02 23:00:00    [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [...
```

result -> 
`2008-07-01 [[24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0], [24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, [...
2008-07-02 [[24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0], [24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0, [...`

Or is a proper approach to use a for loop ?
I am not very satisfied using loops in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a `groupby` + `np.sum` operation on your data.

```
s.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1D')).apply(np.sum, axis=0)

2008-07-01    [[24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0], [24.0, 24.0, 24.0, ...
2008-07-02    [[24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0], [24.0, 24.0, 24.0, ...
2008-07-03    [[24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0], [24.0, 24.0, 24.0, ...
Freq: D, dtype: object
```

Comment: wow thank you ! with pythons numpy and pandas there a so much possibilities